# Filter a json dataset by a field 4 levels deep

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

Take the following json structure, how can I filter it on the categories node that is 4 levels down.

For example, only return a json object which contains items that have "cat8" in this example, i'd get Items A and B?

I'm using node and have lodash installed.

I would filter the data at source normally, but the dataset I have, I can't do this.

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "fields": {
                "title": "Item A",
                "section1": {
                    "fields": {
                        "title": "Level 2 title",
                        "section2": {
                            "fields": {
                                "title": "Level 3 title",
                                "section3": {
                                    "fields": {
                                        "title": "Level 4 title",
                                        "categories": [
                                            "cat1",
                                            "cat6",
                                            "cat8"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "title": "Item B",
                "section1": {
                    "fields": {
                        "title": "Level 2 title",
                        "section2": {
                            "fields": {
                                "title": "Level 3 title",
                                "section3": {
                                    "fields": {
                                        "title": "Level 4 title",
                                        "categories": [
                                            "cat1",
                                            "cat8"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "title": "Item C",
                "section1": {
                    "fields": {
                        "title": "Level 2 title",
                        "section2": {
                            "fields": {
                                "title": "Level 3 title",
                                "section3": {
                                    "fields": {
                                        "title": "Level 4 title",
                                        "categories": [
                                            "cat1",
                                            "cat3"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with lodash its pretty simple

```js
const results = _.filter(deepObject,['path.to.deep.property', expectedValue])
```

Comment: this has done the trick. I was using a where and I couldn't figure out how to get the deep path to work. Got it working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure in advance, you could visit all objects and check if the values contains the wanted value.

```js
const
    hasCategory = o => Object
        .values(o)
        .some(p => p === category || p && typeof p === 'object' && hasCategory(p)),
    data = { items: [{ fields: { title: "Item A", section1: { fields: { title: "Level 2 title", section2: { fields: { title: "Level 3 title", section3: { fields: { title: "Level 4 title", categories: ["cat1", "cat6", "cat8"] } } } } } } } }, { fields: { title: "Item B", section1: { fields: { title: "Level 2 title", section2: { fields: { title: "Level 3 title", section3: { fields: { title: "Level 4 title", categories: ["cat1", "cat8"] } } } } } } } }, { fields: { title: "Item C", section1: { fields: { title: "Level 2 title", section2: { fields: { title: "Level 3 title", section3: { fields: { title: "Level 4 title", categories: ["cat1", "cat3"] } } } } } } } }] },
    category = 'cat8',
    result = data.items.filter(hasCategory);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```